# Marge array in a function both sorted and unsorted

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I have a function where I pass arrays that are both sorted and unsorted. The function working when both arrays are sorted but when I pass unsorted then it doesn't sort the array and marge it.

Example code:

```
// Marge sorted array 
const arrayOne = [1,3,5,11,18];
const arrayTwo = [9, 15, 111, 131, 172];

function margeArray(arrOne, arrTwo){
  const margedArray = [];
  let arrOneItem = arrOne[0];
  let arrTwoItem = arrTwo[0]
  let i = 1;
  let j = 1;

  //Check input
  if(arrOne.length === 0) {
    return arrTwo;
  };

  if(arrTwo.length === 0) {
    return arrOne;
  };

  while(arrOneItem || arrTwoItem) {
    if(!arrTwoItem || arrOneItem < arrTwoItem) {
       margedArray.push(arrOneItem);
       arrOneItem = arrOne[i];
       i++;
    }else {
       margedArray.push(arrTwoItem);
       arrTwoItem = arrTwo[j];
       j++;
    }
  }

  return margedArray;
}

margeArray(arrayOne, arrayTwo)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the spread syntax [...] to join the arrays and sort to sort the merge.

```js
// Merge sorted array 
const arrayOne = [11,18,1,3,5];
const arrayTwo = [9,131,172,15,111];
const msorted = [...arrayOne, ...arrayTwo].sort((a,b) => a-b);
console.log(msorted)
```

Answer (score 1):

You implicitly assume the next added element will be smaller than any other element in the remaining part of both your arrays. This is only true when both input arrays are already sorted. So it's perfectly normal to get an incorrect result when passing unsorted arrays to your function.

Of course you can use JavaScript native array methods to do the job in one line of code, relying on primitives that are being tested a few million times per second across the browsers of the world since 1995 :)

That seems like the wise thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a lot easier by `.concat`enating the two arrays and then `.sort` them numerically.

```js
// Merge sorted array 
const arrayOne = [1,3,5,11,18];
const arrayTwo = [9, 15, 111, 131, 172];

function mergeArray(arrOne, arrTwo){
  return arrOne.concat(arrTwo).sort((a,b) => a-b)
}

console.log(mergeArray(arrayOne, arrayTwo));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want just use native `sort` method?:

```
function margeArra(arrOne, arrTwo) {
    return [...arrOne, ...arrTwo].sort(function(a, b) {
        return a - b;
    })
}
```